# iPhone - Play Youtube video by UIWebView

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, embed, mpmovieplayercontroller

**update**

I have uploaded it to github, the link is https://github.com/ThinkChris/YouTubeDemo/blob/master/tabtest/FirstViewController.m

The requirement is:

1. the app (based on tabviewcontroller) wont be rotated
2. the embeded youtube video should get into fullscreen in portrait mode
3. the fullscreen video can be rotated (portrait and landscape)

---

Hi folks I have two blocks of codes to embed youtube video in a uiwebview, i notice that effects are different. aren't they all MPMoviePlayerController? why there are difference?

code 1:video starts in portrait fullscreen, rotation restricted by viewcontroller (video cannot be retated if the viewcontroll cannot do so)

```
- (void)addYouTubeVideoWebView:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    // iframe
    url = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/IQGhq0IlVok";
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html>\
        <body style=\"margin:0\">\
            // HERERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
            <iframe src=\"%@?showinfo=0\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>\
        </body>\
    </html>\
    ";

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

    UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

code 2: start in landscape fullscreen, can rotate to any direction by itself

```
- (void)addYouTubeVideoWebView:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    // embed
    url = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQGhq0IlVok";
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html>\
        <body style=\"margin:0\">\
            // HERERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
            <embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\"%@\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body>\
    </html>\
    ";

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

    UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an iframe is embedding a HTML document inside a HTML document. But as your iframe doesn't contain a valid HTML document (only an URL), my guess is that the browser doesn't have enough information about your iframe and can't decide if it can be played in landscape (why would it be like this, I don't know, it's just a guess).

- try setting a width and a height for your iframe or
- try using the full HTML code for the embed version in the iframe version:

  ```
  <html>\
    <body style='margin:0'>\
      <iframe width'%0.0f' height='%0.0f' frameborder='0'>
        <html>\
          <body style='margin:0'>\
            <embed type='application/x-shockwave-flash' src='%@' width='%0.0f' height='%0.0f'></embed>\
          </body>\
        </html>\
      </iframe>\
    </body>\
  </html>\";
  ```

Comment: Thanks @teriiehina, for advices and codes, but above code cannot work, the youtube thumb not showing.

Comment: Ok, my bad, should have tested  before submitting. And what happens if you give  a width and a height to your  iframe ? (I'm in the commute, I'll give this a deeper look when I arrive at my office)

Comment: thank you very much, i have uploaded it to github and also updated the question. please have a look